# Javascript JSON post to PHP; Values not passing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, parameter-passing, json

I understand there are numerous threads with this very same problem, but I feel like I've read them all 10 times over, and I am going crazy here...

I am making a post with Javascript/Ajax to a PHP page. First I create an object with key : value pair. Then I stringify the object. The result is:

`{"ID":"150433699","FileNo":"1114"} \\I have tried putting singles quotes on the ends of the string`

Ajax Post:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type:"POST",
    url:"<mydomain>/valupd.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data:jsonStr //This variable is what I used to output the json listed above.
});
```

PHP Code:

```
$json = $_REQUEST["jsonStr"];
$JD = json_decode($json, true);
$id = $JD['ID'];
```

I didn't include my SQL connection, because it works. The record is inserted with blank or default values, unless I put a check in place, in which case it does not add the record.

I've also created another test php page. Then declared a string variable using the output of console.log(jsonStr) as it's value. - Which is the same output as the json string listed earlier. I used the exact same PHP code as listed above to handle that string and was able to echo the value of FileNo.

Comment: Instead of stringifying to jsonStr just keep it in object notation.... on the php side your should be able to access the properties of the object as normal post superglobals i.e. $_POST["ID"] and $_POST["FileNo"]

Comment: You're not including a field name in your ajax call, so the json string is being sent across as a bare string, meaning it won't be available in $_POST, try `$json = file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of `$json = $_POST['jsonStr']`.

Comment: @MarcB: Looks like an answer to me :)

Comment: @MarcB: Using the file_get_contents example...I would then decode $json, and then be able to access it like

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$id = $data['ID'];

? I tried this and still getting nothing.

Comment: With the updated code just use `$id = $_POST["ID"]` drop the other two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off when you are posting a to php from javascript make sure your data is a json object, don't run it through JSON.stringify.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type:"POST",
    url:"<mydomain>/valupd.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data:jsonObj //This should be an object
});
```

When you perform the call then the properties in the json object will become entryies in the $_POST php superglobal.

So given a Post that looks like

```
 {"ID":"150433699","FileNo":"1114"}
```

You will be able to access the properties as

```
 $id = $_POST["ID"];
 $fileNo = $_POST["FileNo"];
```

Comment: Thanks for writing it out for me...I was trying so many different ways I think I actually started combining parts...This worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax-side call should be

```
data: 'jsonStr='+jsonStr
       ^^^^^^^--fieldname
                 ^^^^^^^---value
```

which would allow `$_POST['jsonStr']` to work. Otherwise, since there's no field name, `$_POST[]` cannot be populated - you have to have a key:value relationship, and you've provided no key.

The other workaround is

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

to retrieve the RAW post data in PHP, which would read that json string in directly.